# What does "after" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I wonder what "after" means in this context. Does it mean that the chair is a replica or an original?

> A mid century Wassily / B3 chair 1925-1927, after Marcel Breuer (New York, 1902-1981).

Comment: This is not really an answer, as I don't know, but I think they are referring to an "epoch" of which Marcel Breuer was prominent and influential. So when it says "after" they are saying that the chair was made after his time.

Comment: @A. Kvåle: If the chair was actually made ***by*** Marcel Breuer, that highlighted preposition would normally be used. I think here, ***after*** simply means ***after / following / consistent with the style of*** - which could refer to "imitations / copies / knock-offs" made while Breuer himself was still producing "originals".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aha, that makes sense. I didn't actually know one could use "after" in that way, or at least it was deep down in my memory. +1

Comment: I've included a link to the relevant OED definition in a comment under @tchrist's answer, but I'm afraid it's behind a paywall for many. Apart from the fact that ***by*** specifically *isn't* used, I'd point out that one reasonable paraphrase of ***after*** here would be ***replicating [the style of]*** - so you can be quite certain it won't be an "original" (work by Breuer).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, absolutely, it just means: in the style of, and is used all the time  in design/art.

Answer (score 6):

This means that the “Wassily” chair is one in the design of one originally made by someone named “Marcel Breuer” of New York. Think of it as saying that it was named *for* his style of making chairs—or if you would, that it was named *after* his style. Or even that it was named *because of* him, for it was made in his style.

[image: Wassily Chair image from Wikipedia]

<sub><sub>Image credit: [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Bauhaus_Chair_Breuer.png)</sub></sub>

Your citation is an example of [OED sense 10 for the preposition *after*](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/3661) (paywalled). There are three subsenses:

> - a. In accordance with, according to (an example, manner, pattern, custom, idea, etc.).
> - b.  In the manner of, in the same way as; in emulation of; like. Also with verbs of naming or designating: in imitation or memory of.
> - c. In imitation of, in the style of (an artist or work). Also: in resemblance of, representing (a person or thing).

Of those, the operative one that best applies here is subsense c, being in the style of certain artist’s work.

Here are a tiny subset of citations for those three senses, arranged chronologically:

> > - 1850  A. Jameson *Sacred & Legendary Art* 1
> >       A portfolio of prints after the old masters.
> > - 1908  U. Sinclair *Metropolis* xvi. 279
> >       Here was a woman who costumed herself after figures in famous paintings.
> > - 1912  *Times* 3 June 6/1
> >       The velvet brocade material..was woven after an English design.
> > - 1918  N. Bartley *Bargain True* xv. 238
> >       He took her gravely to task for..fancying the world to be regulated after her own notions.
> > - 1924  A. F. Major tr. J. Brøndsted *Early Eng. Ornament* iii. 293
> >       He christens them [sc. rune-stones] after the reddish sandstone,..the ‘Ringerike Group’.
> > - 1990  *Antique Collector* Oct. 64 (*caption*)
> >        A painted enamel plaque after Philippe Mercier.
> > - 1995  C. Hamnett in T. Butler & M. Savage *Social Change & Middle Classes* xv. 262
> >       Jager argues, after Baudrillard, that socially produced objects can express the same logic as conspicuous leisure.
> > - 2002  J. Grieve tr. Proust *In Shadow of Young Girls in Flower* ii. 386
> >       At the very bottom of this *Harmony in Grey and Pink* after Whistler, a tiny moth [etc.].
> > - 2004  R. Dew & P. Pape *No Backup* i. 6
> >       Woven moccasins called opanci, which had a curled toe after the Turkish custom.

In its [eponymous article on the Wassily Chair, Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wassily_Chair) that:

> The Wassily Chair, also known as the Model B3 chair, was designed by Marcel Breuer in 1925-1926 while he was the head of the cabinet-making workshop at the Bauhaus, in Dessau, Germany.
>
> Despite popular belief, the chair was not designed for the non-objective painter Wassily Kandinsky, who was on the Bauhaus faculty at the same time. Kandinsky had admired the completed design, and Breuer fabricated a duplicate for Kandinsky's personal quarters. The chair became known as "Wassily" decades later, when it was re-released by Italian manufacturer Gavina, who had learned of the anecdotal Kandinsky connection in the course of its research on the chair's origins.

Comment: I think you're mistaken! The cited usage is nothing to do with "source of name" (which clearly *was* Kandinsky not Breuer, whatever the precise circumstances). The meaning of ***after*** here is [the full OED's definition IV 10c](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/3661?rskey=xY2F9x&result=3#eid) *In imitation of, **in the style of** (an artist or work). Also: in resemblance of, representing (a person or thing).*

Comment: ...You might find [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XQVfczef-U8C&pg=PA211&dq=%22painting+after+picasso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiP9-Sbq_nbAhWB-KQKHR_9DecQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22painting%20after%20picasso%22&f=false) interesting (I did!). I "sorta" knew without being consciously aware of it that French ***d'après*** covers much the same ground as our ***after*** here. And as that links points out / implies, both can sometimes be used to mean ***adapted from*** (some "original" work in a different medium or language, such as ***a movie after a play by Ibsen***).

Comment: (Except it's a slightly "highbrow" usage, so a more credible example might be *A stage production after a poem by William Blake*.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers `...---...` I kindly invite you to edit my answer to improve it, as I’m rather tied up right now and my kidnappers only let me tap things out in Morse code.

Comment: No worries. I'd better come clean and admit I just skimmed the first and last paragraphs of your answer when I first commented (and downvoted, but I'll cancel that in a mo). You have actually covered the "non-nominative" sense I was banging on about - but it was in the middle, and I missed it first time around. *My* captors let me use a keyboard most days, but they're gonna drag me off to be force-fed my tea any minute, so I'll have to leave it to you to make a change if you want to / have time later.